# Telegram WebApp Bot

Tags: angular, web-applications, bots, telegram

i creating the telegram webapp bot. All working done, but main button does not sending data to the bot but I ran into a problem - data is not sent when the button is clicked, or it is not displayed at all under the right conditions.. What am I doing wrong?
the button should be displayed if any value is entered in the input field and should send data to the bot when it is clicked, but nothing happens, what is wrong in my code?
telegram.webapp.mainbutton doesn't working correctly for me

```
sendCallback() {
    const data = {
      city: this.form.controls.city.value,
      street: this.form.controls.street.value,
      organization: this.form.controls.organization.value,
    };
    WebApp.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
  checkInputs(): void {
    if (this.form.controls.street || this.form.controls.city) {
      WebApp.MainButton.setParams({
        text: 'завершить',
      });
      WebApp.MainButton.show();
      WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', this.sendCallback);
      WebApp.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', this.sendCallback);
    } else {
      WebApp.MainButton.hide();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
sendCallback(): void {
  const data = {
    city: this.form.controls.city.value,
    street: this.form.controls.street.value,
    organization: this.form.controls.organization.value,
  };
  WebApp.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
}

checkInputs(): void {
  if (this.form.controls.street.value || this.form.controls.city.value) {
    WebApp.MainButton.setParams({
      text: 'завершить',
    });
    WebApp.MainButton.show();
    WebApp.onEvent('mainButtonClicked', this.sendCallback.bind(this));
    WebApp.offEvent('mainButtonClicked', this.sendCallback.bind(this));
  } else {
    WebApp.MainButton.hide();
  }
}
```

Make sure you have properly set up the form and called the **checkInputs()** function when the input values change.

Comment: from where i must call the sendData method?